# CGAL - Is it possible to compute the NFP of polygons with holes

Tags: computational-geometry, cgal

I'm considering to use the library CGAL for the calculation of the No-Fit Polygon (NFP). I've seen that the package of 2D Minkowski Sums in CGAL is a great tool for this. However, I would need to compute the NFP for very different types of polygons, and I'm not sure whether CGAL is going to cover my needs when polygons include holes. My doubts are motivated by the following statement found in their documentation website, in the Chapter 2D Minkowski Sums:
"(...)Applications of some of the operations in this package are restricted to polygons that do not contain holes. (Resulting sums may contain holes though.)"

Does anyone know which are those operations that are restricted to polygons without holes? Beyond that, I would appreciate any piece of advice from anybody   who used CGAL to calculate the NFP for non-convex polygons. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As of release 4.9 of CGAL the "2D Minkowski Sum" package supports the construction of Minkowski sums of polygons with holes. This construction can be done with either the convex decomposition or the reduced-convolution methods. The latter is the default and the most efficient in most cases. We have retained all older methods, because they do exhibit better performance in some less frequent cases. You shouldn't have any problem computing the NFP of polygons with holes using the package.